# Cmake recompiles everything each time I add a new source subfolder

Tags: c++, cmake, organization

I have a project tree organized as the following:

```
MyProjects/ - build - project1 - CMakeLists.txt
            |       | project2 - CMakeLists.txt
            |
            | src - project1 - Project1Class1.h
                             | Project1Class1.cpp
                             | Project1Class2.h
                             | Project1Class2.cpp
                             | more subdirectories ...
                    project2 - Project2Class1.h
                             | Project2Class1.cpp
                             | more subdirectories ...
```

Imagine that project2 depends on project1. Then project2 uses directly project1 files and does not use a static or dynamic project1 library. 
Then project2/CMakeLists.txt finds out the project1 and project2 source files and includes them through a GLOB_RECURSE :

```
file(
    GLOB_RECURSE
    source_files
    ../../project1/
    ../../project2/
)
```

This is working in the sense that it correctly builds my projects.

Each time I add a new source file in a new folder, in e.g. file MyNewFolder/myTest.cpp in  src/project2/, and type

```
~/MyProjects/build/project2/$  cmake .
~/MyProjects/build/project2/$  make
```

Then the file is correctly taken into account by cmake. However, my problem is that every file is recompiled again.

Same thing when I change a source file in project1 and try to compile project2.

Note that I considerably simplified what really is in my CMakeLists.txt. So my question is: based on what I explained about it, is this behavior what CMake is expected to do? And if yes what is the rationale behind it and what should I do for `make` to only compile the new file? I was not able to find any documentation about it on the internet.

Note: Feel free to discuss the overall source build files organization. Notice that I wanted to keep my build configuration separated from the src/ folder.

Edit: I found [this](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/file-GLOB-td7121859.html) which explains why GLOB and GLOB_RECURSE prevent it to work.

Edit 2: Even with no GLOB, the compilation is done from the begining is other cases (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655138/cmake-recompiles-everything-each-time-i-add-a-new-directory-in-include-directory) question)

Comment: Do you add .cpp only or .h as well? Is that .h included somewhere?

Comment: I edited my post. Actually, everything re-compiles if the new file is in a new folder

Comment: @StenSoft Yes, .h files are included through include_directories(). The list of all subdirectories is determined through another GLOB_RECURSE

Answer (score 3):

You are observing known side effect of `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)`. I'm not sure why exactly this is happening, but to avoid this most CMake-based projects lists their sources explicitly:

```
set(source_files
  ../../project1/Project1Class1.cpp
  ../../project1/Project1Class2.cpp
  ...
  ../../project2/Project2Class1.cpp
  ../../project2/Project2Class1.cpp
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you  for  the answer. You say "known side effect"  and "most CMake-based projects" : can you give me references please? And if you list them explicitly, how do you do that: by hand or with the help of some kind of sed script on the CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: From the docs: (We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.)

Comment: Out of my head - LLVM project is large enough ( http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/CodeGen/CMakeLists.txt?view=markup ). Yes, they are listed by hand. It's not that tiresome as you might think.

Comment: @trenki Thank you for this reference to the docs. I understand that the generated build system does not know. But it should be possible to force cmake to regenerate even if there is no apparent change to CMakeLists.txt. I do not understand why GLOB_RECURSE does not have the same effect as giving by hand the same files GLOB_RECURSE would have generated. This simply does not seem coherent

Comment: @arrowdodger Thanks for the reference. But I really don't see any reason to list source files by hand. I mean, any source file in the source directory is meant to be build, why should I bother specify it for each file? Maybe on some projects this is not the case, but this seems to be a reasonable default behavior that ought to be supported...

Comment: Honestly, i don't see the rationale behind this too. But judging from that it's a very long-standing problem, i suppose there is some fundamental issue that prevent `file(GLOB ...)` from invalidating targets cache.