# Cmake recompiles everything each time I add a new directory in include_directory()

Tags: build, cmake, build-process

(This question is quite similar to [this one I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521613/cmake-recompiles-everything-each-time-i-add-a-new-source-subfolder) but is not related to the GLOB subtleties. So separating the two problems would be clearer I think)

Each time I add or remove a folder in include_directory() (even empty) in my CMakeLists.txt, then typing

```
cmake .
make
```

triggers the whole project to be recompiled. Why and what can I do about it?

My actual CMakeLists.txt (note there is no GLOB):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
cmake_policy(VERSION 2.8.12.2)

# Project
get_filename_component(ProjectName MyProject NAME)
project(${ProjectName})

# Compiler and options
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/clang++)
set(CLANG_COMPILE_FLAGS "-std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ ")

# Type of build
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
# Build tool 
set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles")

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ../bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CLANG_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${CLANG_LINK_FLAGS}")

include_directories(
    [all folders containing .h files here] # adding anything here triggers the whole project to recompile
)

add_executable(
    ${ProjectName}
    [all .cpp and .h files here]
)
```

Comment: @ruslo my source are not within the current dir. Hence my object files are not mixed up with sources.

Comment: @ruslo Thanks for the "Release" tip

Comment: @ruslo In fact my CMakeLists.txt is generated from a script (this is recent and done in order to solve the problem mentioned in my previous question - link above). I do not change often between Debug and Release so I just change manually. But I very well admit that this is not very clean. From what I've seen though, no C++ build process is clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `include_directories` add compiler flags (e.g. `-I/path/to/include/dir` for `gcc`). So if you change `include_directories` => compiler flags changes => target need to be rebuild.

#### Example

To avoid regular recompilation of whole project you need to not modify `include_directories` often. As an example you can organize code like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
Source/
        - A/foo.hpp
        - A/foo.cpp
        - B/boo.hpp
        - B/boo.cpp
```

Content of CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(./Source)
add_executable(myexe A/foo.hpp A/foo.cpp B/boo.hpp B/boo.cpp)
```

Content of C++ files:

```
#include "A/foo.hpp"
#include "B/boo.hpp"
```

Comment: Ok. Hence, there is no solution to my problem right ? Either I accept a full recompilation each time I decide to add a new folder to my source tree, or I simply decide to put everything inside a big folder (or some compromise between the two). I honestly can't understand why this recompilation needs to happen.

Comment: And your answer seems to imply that it does not come from cmake nor make, so I guess that whether I choose any build system with any compiler I should have the same problem right ?

Comment: @Bérenger `I honestly can't understand why this recompilation needs to happen` you compiler flags changes, hence file need to be recompiled. Otherwise compiler need to be **very** smart to decide that everything up to date (it's not CMake issue).

Comment: @Bérenger `And your answer seems to imply that it does not come from cmake nor make` exactly

Comment: @Bérenger why do you need to change 'include_directories' so often? Usually I add only 'Source' directory to the includes and only files that have some c++ '#include <...>' line need to be rebuild when I add new header.

Comment: Ok I found a way to deal with it nevertheless: just symlink every header and source into one only directory from which the project is built. Not clean because of name conflicts but I have none of these so it is ok for me for now. I'll post an answer if I am still satisfied with it in a couple of month

Comment: I am not sure to understand how you do it. For me, each time I find that some files are closely related I put them inside a new directory, both .h and .cpp. MyClass.h and MyClass.cpp are in the same directory

Comment: @Bérenger `just symlink every header and source` are you kidding? :) you've created new script that produce CMakeLists.txt, then run cmake to produce make and now you're running some symlink magic!? Just stop using GLOB_RECURSE for collecting sources (that's explicitly not recommended in documentation and now you know the reason) and include new headers so they fit the location: `Sources/A/B/foo.hpp` => `#include "A/B/foo.hpp"`. That's all. I see no problems here.

Comment: I am not using glob_recurse anymore. Since cmake is not capable of doing it without recompiling uneededly, the script does generate it (so cmake sees it as if given by hand). So this problem is solved (and I do not see any way to solve it more cleanly, but if you do, see discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28536208/1583122, you can post an answer)

Comment: Now concerning #include "A/B/foo.hpp", first, source and header are then in a different folders, which is not practical. Second, if you decide that the header would be better in folder "C/D/foo.hpp", then you have to change every occurence which is also annoying. I mean, it would certainly be cleaner, but my packaging is not stable so it is not the best solution for me now.

Comment: I liked the "are you kidding" though :)  I have been wondering for a long time how to organize files but never found any tutorial or standard way to do it. My position for now is to wait for the module TR

Comment: @Bérenger `first, source and header are then in a different folders` why do you think they need to be in different folders with such approach? See [example](https://github.com/ruslo/sober/tree/master/Source/sober/network/http). `then you have to change every occurence which is also annoying` why not to use script?

Comment: `first...` ok my bad I misunderstood. Yes using a script is possible. However, you still have to do this refactoring each time you change the location of your files. But I'll buy your argument. Can you sum it up on the answer or link to some reference explaining how to organize sources? I've never been able to find such a thing. I'll the accept your answer as solving my problem. Thank you!